# Replacing part of a path name with search variable?

Tags: path, cmd.exe

I'm not sure if I have used the right expression in the question, but the context totally slips my mind.

I am trying to write a script to go to a student folder, depending on who is logged in, but I don't want to decide all of the folders it must use.

For example -
If I want to access student A, I would search

```
\\Server\Students\Cohort10\user
```

But student B could be found in

```
\\Server\Students\Cohort08\user
```

As you can see, the cohort folders cause a problem for predefined paths because they are different.

So is there a way to type \server\Students\VARIABLE\user

I thought the variable was $ or * or something like that.

Comment: The word you are looking for is probably wildcard. See http://superuser.com/questions/709651/how-to-perform-wildcard-string-comparison-in-batch-file

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PowerShell:

> The * wildcard will match zero or more characters
>
> The ? wildcard will match a single character
>
> [m-n] Match a range of characters from m to n, so [f-m]ake will match
>   fake/jake/make
>
> [abc] Match a set of characters a,b,c.., so [fm]ake will match
>   fake/make
>
> PowerShell wildcards are consistent in their meaning so using *.* will
>   match any characters followed by a period (.) followed by any
>   characters. In other words *.* will return only files that have an
>   extension, not directories. To return all items just use a single *
>   This is quite different to the behaviour seen under the CMD shell.
>
> When using WMI filters use the WMI specific wildcards: % for zero or
>   more characters, _ for a single character.
>
> Wildcards will also work within both single and double quotes, to
>   prevent wildcard expansion use the -LiteralPath parameter where
>   available.
>
> Examples
>
> PS C:> Get-ChildItem c:\work*.xls
>
> PS C:> Get-ChildItem c:\work[a-f]*.txt
>
> PS C:> Get-ChildItem -literalpath 'c:\work\test[1].txt'

[Source](http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-wildcards.html)

Comment: in powershell, how would you specify  `c:\abc\def\..`  <-- where `..` means the regex `..` rather than the go back a directory `..` ?

Comment: The * and ? wildcards work in cmd/batch as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think what your looking for is %VARIABLE%, e.g.

```
echo %TMP%
```

will replace %TMP% with the value for that environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

While there is %USERPROFILE%, Maybe you want something like `c:\blah\*\user`

cmd can't do `c:\blah\*\user`

i'm not sure about powershell.

Linux shells eg bash does though.. and you could use cygwin, as cygwin can do it for you, giving you a bash shell in Windows.

Here we have a directory structure of

```
az\b\sdf\c\
az\b\qwer\c
```

You can use a wildcard in bash in the middle of a path.  This is from cygwin

```
$ ls -l az/b/*/c
az/b/qwer/c:
total 0

az/b/sdf/c:
total 0
```

You can access your main files in cygwin by /cygdrive/c/...